# Solving Second Order differential equation using Variation of Parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

my homework asks us to find the particular solution to a second Order non-homogeneous differential equation with given y1 and y2 in which we are supposed to use to use along with the formula of Variation of Parameters.

What have i tried? Well, I've tried using Method of Undetermined Coefficients to check my work but i keep getting a different answer, and I've confirmed that the second particular solution(Through Undetermined Coefficients) I've obtained is correct.

Problem:What is the mistake i am making when i am using Variation of Parameters? I keep getting $\frac{-xcos + sinx}{2}$ when the CORRECT answer is $\frac{-xcosx}{2}$ as seen through the Method of Undetermined Coefficients

Thank you all.

[Variation Of Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsULK.jpg)

[Method of Undetermined Coefficients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTfW6.jpg)

Comment: The least you could do is to make your pictures legible (and horizontal). Better yet, please use MathJax to type out every relevant equation to point out (1) the problem statement (2) your solution (3) which part you feel contains a mistake and what exactly are you unsure about

Answer (score 1):

The $\sin x/2$ bit is part of the homogeneous solution, so it would normally be dropped.